# Python - How to get all instances instead of just the first on the page

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

Using `findAll` gives the error "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str", where using `.find` didn't.  Using `findall` gives the error "TypeError: 'NoneType' object is not callable".

What is the correct way to target all links that have a class of "frame" on the page, instead of just the first instance?

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = ("http://www.gym-directory.com/listing-category/gyms-fitness-centres/")
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
print soup.findAll("a",{"class":"frame"})["href"]

url = ("http://www.gym-directory.com/listing-category/gyms-fitness-centres/page/2/")
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
print soup.findAll("a",{"class":"frame"})["href"]

url = ("http://www.gym-directory.com/listing-category/gyms-fitness-centres/page/3/")
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
print soup.findAll("a",{"class":"frame"})["href"]

url = ("http://www.gym-directory.com/listing-category/gyms-fitness-centres/page/4/")
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
print soup.findAll("a",{"class":"frame"})["href"]

url = ("http://www.gym-directory.com/listing-category/gyms-fitness-centres/page/5/")
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
print soup.findAll("a",{"class":"frame"})["href"]

url = ("http://www.gym-directory.com/listing-category/gyms-fitness-centres/page/6/")
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
print soup.findAll("a",{"class":"frame"})["href"]

url = ("http://www.gym-directory.com/listing-category/gyms-fitness-centres/page/7/")
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
print soup.findAll("a",{"class":"frame"})["href"]

url = ("http://www.gym-directory.com/listing-category/gyms-fitness-centres/page/8/")
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
print soup.findAll("a",{"class":"frame"})["href"]

url = ("http://www.gym-directory.com/listing-category/gyms-fitness-centres/page/9/")
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.text, 'html.parser')
print soup.findAll("a",{"class":"frame"})["href"]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The issue is that `soup.findAll()` returns a `list`, and you are trying to access that list with `["href"]`

What you need to do is:

```
for elem in soup.findAll("a", {"class": "frame"}):
    print elem["href"]
```