# how to loop using beautifulsoup

Tags: python

I am trying to scrape data on car model, price, mileage, location, etc using beautifulsoup. However, the return result only reports data on one random car. I want to be able to collect data on all cars advertised on the site to date. My python code is below. How can I modify my code to retrieve data such that each day I have information on car model, price, mileage, location, etc? Example:

1. Car model price mileage location date
2. Toyota Corrola $4500 22km Accra 16/02/2018
3. Nissan Almera $9500 60km Tema 16/02/2018

etc

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas
import csv
from datetime import datetime
for i in range(300):       
    url = "https://tonaton.com/en/ads/ghana/cars?".format(i) 
r = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")
print soup.prettify()
data = soup.find(class_='item-content')

for tag in data:    
    item_title = data.find("a",attrs={"class":"item-title h4"})
    model = item_title.text.encode('utf-8').strip()
    item_meta = data.find("p",attrs={"class":"item-meta"})
    mileage = item_meta.text.encode('utf-8').strip()
    item_location = data.find("p",attrs={"class":"item-location"})
    location = item_location.text.encode('utf-8').strip()
    item_info = data.find("p",attrs={"class":"item-info"})
    price = item_info.text.encode('utf-8').strip()           
with open('example.csv', 'a') as csv_file:
    writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
    writer.writerow([model, price, mileage, location, datetime.now()])
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Python - How to get all instances instead of just the first on the page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32814578/python-how-to-get-all-instances-instead-of-just-the-first-on-the-page)

Comment: Use `findAll()`?

Comment: Thanks, David. I have tried that option but unsuccessful before posting. Could you kindly show me how?

Comment: Why were you unsuccessful? Was there an error, wrong output, etc.?

Comment: If I change: `data = soup.find(class_='item-content') to data = soup.findAll(class_='item-content')` I get the error: `AttributeError: ResultSet object has no attribute 'find'. You're probably treating a list of items like a single item. Did you call find_all() when you meant to call find()?`

Comment: And the error message is unclear how exactly?

Comment: Thank you, tripleee, for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, this loop:

```
for i in range(300):       
    url = "https://tonaton.com/en/ads/ghana/cars?".format(i)
```

is not doing what I assume you think it is. This loop simply resets the url 300 times and leaves you with the original url you set. You need to wrap all your code in this loop to ensure you are hitting each of the URLs you want (1-300).

Restructure your code (paying attention to indents!) so that the next url is the one being used in the request:

```
# This will print ALOT of titles
for i in range(300):
    url = "https://tonaton.com/en/ads/ghana/cars?" + str(i) 
    print(url) # Notice how the url changes with each iteration?
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = bsoup(r.content, "html.parser")
    titles = soup.findAll("a",attrs={"class":"item-title h4"})
    for item in titles:
        currTitle = item.text.encode('utf-8').strip()
        print(currTitle)
```

This code:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup

url = "https://tonaton.com/en/ads/ghana/cars?1"
r = requests.get(url)
soup = bsoup(r.content, "html.parser")
titles = soup.findAll("a",attrs={"class":"item-title h4"})
for item in titles:
    print(item.text.encode('utf-8').strip())
```

Yields (not sure what the 'b' is doing):

```
b'Hyundai Veloster 2013'
b'Ford Edge 2009'
b'Mercedes-Benz C300 2016'
b'Mazda Demio 2007'
b'Hyundai Santa fe 2005'
# And so on...
```

The problem is that 1) if you call `find()`, it will stop after you find the first match given your params. Using `findAll()` will dump all matches into a list which you then can iterate through and process as needed. And 2) the result you get from a call to `find()` is a broken structure of the original HTML. Thus the next `find()` calls won't work.

Comment: Thanks David. I followed your suggestion, and because this worked for car model, I assumed it should work for the rest. However, the result is one row as before. I am still new to python. So, I guess I am doing something wrong. For url, you are right. I want to retrieve all pages. I am not sure how to wrap the loop. Please see my code below. Thanks very much.

Comment: Hi David, thank you very much. Your code worked. I just need two things, sorry to be too demanding. (1) Instead of `print(item.text.encode('utf-8').strip())` how do I name it for conversion to csv. Python prints just one row if I assign say `model = item.text.encode('utf-8').strip()`. (2) I have read most of the responses on how to loop multiple pages but none has worked so far. Instead of `for i in range(300):
url = "https://tonaton.com/en/ads/ghana/cars?".format(i)`, how best can I loop over these pages? Thanks in advance.

Comment: 1) Regarding this line, `print(item.text.encode('utf-8').strip())` I was just printing the result rather than storing it in a variable and printing the variable. You can assign it like you already were: ` someVar = item.text.encode('utf-8').strip()` . 2) I suggest you do some more reading on python. Indentation is very important in python, any code indented after a for loop will be ran the number of iterations as the for loop. I will edit it my answer to be more specific/show you.

Comment: Thanks very much, David. I will do some more reading on this. It will be great, if you could help revise this code but I will keep trying.

Comment: Hi David, you have helped me a lot. I know, I will be asking too much but could you kindly help me figure out why writing the data into a csv file with the following gives me just one row: `with open('data.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
                writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
                writer.writerow([model, price, mileage, location, datetime.now()])`? Results: `Chevrolet AVEO 2006,"GHâ‚µ 27,000","66,542 km","MEMBERAccra, Cars",2018-02-17 06:41:58.497000`

Comment: It's because you keep overwriting the variables you are trying to write. If i assign `x = 2` then `x = 3`. The value stored in `x` will no longer be 2, it will be 3. You must add each data point (`title`, `mileage`, etc.) into their own lists. Then, iterate through those lists and write the variables. Search for "adding variables to lists" and "writing lists to file" and you will find answers.

Comment: Hi David, thanks very much for your explanation. I will look that up.

Answer (score 0):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bsoup
import csv
from datetime import datetime
for i in range(300):
url = "https://tonaton.com/en/ads/ghana/cars?".format(i)
r = requests.get(url) 
soup = bsoup(r.content, "html.parser") 
item_title = soup.findAll("a",attrs={"class":"item-title h4"})

for item in item_title:
        model = item.text.encode('utf-8').strip()

item_meta = soup.findAll("p",attrs={"class":"item-meta"})
for item in item_meta:
        milleage = item.text.encode('utf-8').strip()

item_location = soup.findAll("p",attrs={"class":"item-location"})
for item in item_location:
        location = item.text.encode('utf-8').strip()

item_info = soup.findAll("p",attrs={"class":"item-info"})        
for item in item_info:
        price = item.text.encode('utf-8').strip()

with open('index.csv', 'w') as csv_file:
        writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
        writer.writerow([model, price, milleage, location, datetime.now()])
```

Comment: Don't post code or responses in the answer section unless it is the **answer** to your question.

Comment: Thank you, David. I wanted to show you the nature of my revised code but the character limit wouldn't allow me. This is why I had to post it as an "answer". I will keep this in mind.